# download XMLs in a ZIP file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, zip

I have a datagridview with many records, one of its fields has the content of an XML file, if I select a row I can download the XML file, but how can I select many rows and download all of the XML files in a ZIP file?

I know how to get a checbox in each row and check whether it is checked or not, but have no clue on the rest

Btw, I'm using C# ASP.NET 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used this free library before - it never let me down: http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/

Just pull out the DLL file that fits best for your needs and drop it in as a reference to your project. If you're building a website, make sure the Ionic dll gets uploaded with your site bin so it can be loaded/used.

Hope this helps!

Comment: it worked, i wrote xml files in a folder, created the zip file and a link so user can download it, thank you